# How can I encode string to UTF8 WideString on Delphi XE5?

Tags: string, delphi, unicode, encoding, utf-8

How can I encode `string` to UTF8 `string` on Delphi XE5? When I'm trying to convert UTF8 encoded string to `string` type I lose UTF8 encoding:

```
Result := string(Utf8Encode(ASource));
```

Comment: What is the type of `Result` ? Is that `string` and are you using  Unicode Delphi ? If so, then it's a possible duplicate of [`this question`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2697843/960757). [I have a close voting hammer and want to keep this Q opened since it is not complete...]

Comment: @TLama: Swing the hammer (or I will). It's indeed a duplicate.

Comment: @Ken, that question is a similar mix of `WideString` vs. `UnicodeString`, but yes, [`it's a duplicate`](http://i.imgur.com/Am4co6e.png).

Comment: I cannot understand the question. I don't see any WideString here at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the duplicate question:

```
      aUTF8Str := UTF8Encode(aClientDataSet.Fields[i].DisplayLabel);
      SetCodePage(aUTF8Str, 0, False);
      aUnicodeStr := UnicodeString(aUTF8Str);
      Result := aUnicodeStr;
```

Comment: Converting a `RawByteString` to a `UnicodeString` after forcing the `RawByteString`'s codepage 0 is asking for data lose. CodePage 0 maps to the user's default OS codepage, which could be anything. If you really want to copy the UTF-8 octets as-is into `UnicodeString` characters, you are best off looping through the `RawByteString` manually instead.

Comment: There are no WideString instance here.